# Get Common OS name of Linux Python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to get Linux distro name like centos, fedora, ubuntu, SuSE etc in python.
I made use of platform module.
My code is

```
import platform
version = platform.platform(aliased=0)
version = version.split('-with-',1)[1].split('-',1)[0]
print version
```

It gives me the desired output. But is there any simpler way other than this, or any module which gives me the name directly?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server', '6.6', 'Santiago')
```

Comment: It is working with most distributions. But don't know why I get an error in Redhat.
>>> platform.platform(aliased=0)
'Linux-2.6.18-128.6om-x86_64-with-redhat-7-Moonshine'
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linux_distribution'

Comment: @sudheeshshetty, what is your python version, can you post the output of dir(platform)

Comment: it is python 2.5, I could not see linux_distribution in dir(platform). Though when I pasted the error I got the alternative for that. i.e platform.dist().

Answer (score 0):

what about platform.linux_distribution?

```
In [1]: import platform                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
In [2]: platform.linux_distribution()                                                                                                                         
Out[2]: ('Fedora', '21', 'Twenty One')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
>>> import os
>>> cmd = "lsb_release -si"
>>> os.system(cmd)
Ubuntu
```